# Recursive method of reversing an array step by step

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, reverse

Can someone please explain to me this recursive method of reversing an array step by step?

```
# Recursive python program to reverse an array
# Function to reverse A[] from start to end
   def reverseList(A, start, end):

    if start >= end:

        return

    A[start], A[end] = A[end], A[start]

    reverseList(A, start+1, end-1)

 
# Driver function to test above function

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(A)

reverseList(A, 0, 5)

print("Reversed list is")

print(A)
```

Output :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Reversed list is:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: have you tried to take a piece of paper and "executing" the code yourself? Is there a specific part you are struggling with understanding?

Comment: It's pretty simple, really. Swap the ends, then reverse what's between the ends.

Comment: otherwise just add print(A, start,end)  at the beginning of the function and look at the trace ... that will help you understand

Comment: add `print(A)` under `def` and you'll understand more.

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is starting at the two ends of the function, swapping the start and end indexes, and then moving both indexes one closer towards the center, once the indexes meet, the function returns. So here's what the function is doing each time it is called:

1 2 3 4 5 6 -> 6 2 3 4 5 1 -> 6 5 3 4 2 1 -> 6 5 4 3 2 1

Answer (score 0):

The method takes the first element (with index `start`) and the last element (with index `end`) of the array, and swaps them. It then takes the second element and second-to-last element and swaps them. It keeps going until you reach the middle, where the `start` index is smaller than `end` index.

Answer (score 0):

This works by creating two pointers one at the first of the list and one at the end `start` and `end`, let's call this pair a 'switch' pointers which indicates where items should be switched, and after we switch those elements we move one step in each direction ( start -> end ) & ( end -> start) and we keep doing this until start is greater than end which means we finished the list.

the same implementation using for loop

```
for i in range(int(len(A)/2)):
    A[i], A[len(A) - 1 - i] = A[len(A) - 1 -i],A[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to explain, the numbers in bold are the changes.

start = 0, end = 5, A = 1 2 3 4 5 6 (Input)

start = 0, end = 5, A = **6** 2 3 4 5 **1** (Swap 0th and 5th element from A)

start = **1**, end = **4**, A = **6** 2 3 4 5 **1** (Input for second time)

start = 1, end = 4, A = 6 **5** 3 4 **2** 1 (Swap 1st and 4th element from A)

start = **2**, end = **3**, A = 6 5 4 3 2 1 (Input for third time)

start = 2, end = 3, A = 6 5 **4** **3** 2 1 (Swap 2nd and 3rd element from A)

start = **3**, end = **2**, A = 6 5 4 3 2 1 (Input for forth time)

Return with no changes and you get your final A = 6 5 4 3 2 1